# How to modify orbit script to start on button touched in Unity3d

Tags: c#, android, button, unity-game-engine, orbit

I have the following orbit script working just fine, on a GameObject in Unity3d. I want to have the script run on the GameObject if a GUI.Button is touched on Android device.

Here is the original C# orbir script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Orbiter : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject cube;
public Transform center;
public Vector3 axis = Vector3.up;
public Vector3 desiredPosition;
public float radius = 2.0f;
public float radiusSpeed = 0.5f;
public float rotationSpeed = 80.0f;

void Start () {
cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("MarkerObject");
center = cube.transform;
transform.position = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius + center.position;
radius = 2.0f;
}

void Update () {
transform.RotateAround (center.position, axis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
desiredPosition = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius + center.position;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, Time.deltaTime * radiusSpeed);
}
}
```

Here is the modified code that refuses to run, no matter what I've tried.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Orbiter : MonoBehaviour {

private bool IsOrbited = false;
private bool MustOrbit = false;    
GameObject cube;
public Transform center;
public Vector3 axis = Vector3.up;
public Vector3 desiredPosition;
public float radius = 2.0f;
public float radiusSpeed = 0.5f;
public float rotationSpeed = 80.0f;
public Texture btnTexture2;

 void Start () {
cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("MarkerObject");
center = cube.transform;
transform.position = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius +  center.position;
radius = 2.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (MustOrbit && !IsOrbited) {

        //Rotate all models around X,Y,Z axe
        if (cube != null)
            transform.RotateAround (center.position, axis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            desiredPosition = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius + center.position;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, Time.deltaTime * radiusSpeed);

        IsOrbited = true;
        MustOrbit = false;
        }
}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity,new Vector3(Screen.width / 480.0f, Screen.height / 320.0f, 1)); 
    if (!btnTexture2) {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
        return;
    }
    //GUI.color = new Color(0,0,0,0);
      //GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 120, 30), btnTexture2))
       if (!IsOrbited) {
            MustOrbit = true;
        }
    }
```

}

What have I done wrong in coding? I get compiled o.k. Please advise. 
Thank you all in advace for your answers.

Comment: you toggle IsOrbited and MustOrbit in one cycle of your if statement, try it without changing them after one cycle of your if

Comment: Hello JRowan, thank you for your answer. I knew there must be something wrong with these bools... Could you point me to which part of the script to change? I'm new to Unity and in coding, and I have some trouble getting the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your if statement you are disabling the block from running after 1 iteration resulting in barely any movement, try to comment out disabling the booleans so it can run

```
if (MustOrbit && !IsOrbited) {

        //Rotate all models around X,Y,Z axe
        if (cube != null)
            transform.RotateAround (center.position, axis, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            desiredPosition = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius + center.position;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, desiredPosition, Time.deltaTime * radiusSpeed);

       // IsOrbited = true;
       // MustOrbit = false;
        }
```

to reset the x,y,z on your model in your start get the starting xyz as a vector3

```
public Vector3 reset;
```

in Start()

```
void Start () {
cube = GameObject.FindWithTag("MarkerObject");
center = cube.transform;
transform.position = (transform.position - center.position).normalized * radius +  center.position;
radius = 2.0f;
reset = transform.position;
}
```

then onGUI()

```
void OnGUI() {
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity,new Vector3(Screen.width / 480.0f, Screen.height / 320.0f, 1)); 
    if (!btnTexture2) {
        Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
        return;
    }
    //GUI.color = new Color(0,0,0,0);
      //GUI.backgroundColor = Color.clear;

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 120, 30), btnTexture2))
       if (!IsOrbited) {
            MustOrbit = true;
        }
    }
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width*5/6,Screen.height*5/6,Screen.width/6,Screen.height/6),"reset")){
      transform.position = reset;
    }
```

Comment: JRowan I have tried commenting those bools out before I have posted here my question. Nothing changes but in Unity Inspector the x value to -30 from 0. Is it moving or what? Why it does not rotates as in the original script?

Comment: if (cube != null) is the only difference and that only enables the line after it because theres no brackets, thats the only difference, hitting the button should do what the other script does without a button

Comment: Thank you JRowan for being so kind to explain this difference a newbie, like me. I take your answer as correct. It was the center target, on script settings that was causing the trouble after all. Could you point me to a direction, or give me a code snipet, on how to reset the model to its previous state (x,y,z) adding a e.g. reset button?

Comment: i updated with code to reset position, also you should get in the habbit of making rects acording to Screen.width and Screen.height to make them scalable across devices or platforms

Comment: JRowan your are amazing! Thanks a lot for the snipet. Being a newbie, as I am, I have update the script but I do not get initial position on pressing btnTexture2. Should I make an new script e.g. Reset.cs, with a new button "btnTexture3". If so, how do I link the Orbiter.cs to the new script?

Comment: you can put it in the same script just how you did btnTexture2 just change "reset" in the button with btnTexture3

Comment: use GetComponent() to access another script, heres a link https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: JRowan, you are one of a kind! Being a member of S.O. for about 2 mounths, you are the first person willing enough to answer a bunch of questions. Someone should reward you a badge! Do you happen to know, for quick reference, an active forum about Unity3d, besides the Unity community forum?

Comment: no, i only know this and unity3d's, they are out there though

Comment: O.k., I know there are, but they are less responsive as S.O. is. Anyway, I have added the new GUI.Button as "if(GUI.Button(((new Rect(10,30,120,30) (Screen.width*5/6,Screen.height*5/6,Screen.width/6,Screen.height/6)(Screen.width*5/6,Screen.height*5/6,Screen.width/6,Screen.height/6))),btnTexture3)), and I get the following error: "Expression denotes a `value', where a `method group' was expected (CS0119)". Why is that, wrong?

Comment: There is another point I'd like to ask you @JRowan. The "reset" button should work accordingly to values at x,y,z but instead it moves the 3d model to these axes. What I was asking for, was on how to stop the active orbiting rotation, and reset the model to its previous state,thus before starting the rotation (x,z,y=0). Is this possible? How can I modify the existing code, with the "reset" button add on?